# how can i create a list contain in scrapy

Tags: python

I'm new in Python coming from PHP World, I started using Scrapy to crawl a website and I would like to make a list of URLs depends on the status code,

My problem is I don't get the full list of my URLs when I print the errors variable

this is my code :

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    errors = {
        'statusCode' : {
            '200':{
                'url': []
            },
            '404': {
                'url': []
            },
            '410': {
                'url': []
            },
            '500': {
                'url': []
            },
            '503': {
                'url': []
            }
        }
    }
    if(response.status == 200):
        errors['statusCode']['200']['url'].append(response.url)
    if(response.status == 404):
        errors['statusCode']['404']['url'].append(response.url)
    if(response.status == 410):
        errors['statusCode']['410']['url'].append(response.url)
    if(response.status == 500):
        errors['statusCode']['500']['url'].append(response.url)
    if(response.status == 503):
        errors['statusCode']['503']['url'].append(response.url)

    
    print(errors)
```

Expected result :

```
'statusCode' : {
            '200':{
                'url': [
                    "link1",
                    "link2",
                    "link3"
                ]
            },
            '404': {
                'url': [
                    "link1",
                    "link2",
                    "link3"
                ]
            },
        }
enter code here
```

Comment: do you mind adding some examples which gives unexpected behavior? btw you can just do: `errors['statusCode'][str(response.status)]['url'].append(response.url)` and get rid of all `if`s.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia  can you double check my question, i updated for the expected result 
thanks

Comment: I think the problem is `errors` is local to the method so I am assuming it is only giving the last entry? you need to pass the method the result dictionary and declare it outside.